# How do I push my application out using Phonegap / Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova

I have finished creating my application in JS/CSS/HTML using PhoneGap/Cordova but I cannot figure out how to turn it into a file to submit to the iTunes iOS store. Can anyone explain the necessary steps I need to push my application out?

I have tried searching on Google but I get blurry results. Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: "using PhoneGap/Cordova" ... can you elaborate on that?  Once you've set things up in XCode creating a build for submission is pretty easy.  But setting it up in XCode is pretty involved.  Have you created an iOS app before?

Comment: You need to use itunesconnect for this, you can submit the app from Xcode, if you have an archive

Answer (score 0):

See the [iOS Platform Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide) for steps to get the app running on your device using Xcode (you do need a real iOS device). Once that works, click on Product > Archive. You'll then see the Organizer window with your archive, and from there you will be able to click "Submit to App Store"

PS - "Submit to App Store" will only work if you have created an entry in [iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com) and completed the required information.